# How to make CardView width match it height?

Tags: android, layout

I have a CardView in a LinearLayout. The Layout reserves 1/5 of the screen for the CardView and 4/5 of the screen for other stuff.

I would like the cardview to be square.

I set the CardView's height to "match_parent". But how do I set it's width to match it's height?

Am I going to have to create a custom View and use OnMeasure(), or is there a simpler way?

Here is my view's XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4" >
<!--        Other stuff goes here-->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#81C784"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
            app:cardElevation="3dp"
            app:contentPadding="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/card_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="TEST"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/card_desc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:text="123"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/card_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot of what, roughly, I would like the cardview to look like:
[image]

Comment: Add a image of the desired output that u want.

Comment: Check my answer and reply if you need to change any thing . I will help you to achieve it.

Comment: Screenshot added

Comment: I cant hard code a width because the height of the cardview could change depending on the size of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are looking for an xml way of achieving this it can be done using `ConstraintLayout`. You need to make your cardView's parent layout as constraintlayout instead of LinearLayout, then set constraints and most important part to set

```
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
```

That's it, you just need to give proper values to height and width and this will ensure it to always maintain a 1:1 aspect ratio.

So your code should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4" >
        <!--        Other stuff goes here-->
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <!--  match_parent also works, but use 0dp in constraintLayout as below--> 
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#81C784"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
            app:cardElevation="3dp"
            app:contentPadding="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/card_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="TEST"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/card_desc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="123"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/card_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Notice how i used `W` before `1:1` to show that weight needs to be constrained. based on the height.

This was what the output for above code was

[image: sample output]

Another method If you don't wish to change to constraint layout the other way is to set it programmatically like :

```
CardView cardView = findViewById(R.id.card_view);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = cardView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = params.width;
cardView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

So choose whichever suits you best.

Comment: Thanks! I figured there HAD to be a way to get this accomplished without having to resort to a custom view.